# [xamarin][uwp][custom renderer] custom renderer pcl libarary not loading in release mode

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, custom-renderer

I created PCL library to keep all custom renderers for UWP.
This PCL added to another cross platform application.
its working in debug mode.

But working in release mode.

need help

regards
Sumith

Comment: what are you getting error in debug mode ? can you post here?

Comment: no error in debug mode. The issue is "Renderer pcl not loading in release mode"

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with `Xamarin.Forms` for `UWP`.

To fix it you must register your PCL at start up like so:

```
// you'll need to add `using System.Reflection;`
List<Assembly> assembliesToInclude = new List<Assembly>();

//Now, add in all the assemblies your app uses
assembliesToInclude.Add(typeof(ClassInYourPCL).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

//Also do this for all your other 3rd party libraries

Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e, assembliesToInclude);
// replaces Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);
```

For more info [see here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/#Target_Invocation_Exception_when_using_Compile_with_.NET_Native_tool_chain)